# Maven build failing due to unrecognized `--settings` option

Tags: java, maven

In my Java projects building with maven, I have a a `.mvn` directory that contains a `maven.config` file. Content of that file is as follows:

```
--settings ./.mvn/local-settings.xml
```

The `local-settings.xml` holds authentication credentials for pulling from a private registry.
This setup worked fine up until yesterday. Now, the CI build (using `maven:3-amazoncorretto-17`) is failing with the following error message:

```
Unable to parse maven.config file options: Unrecognized option: --settings ./.mvn/local-settings.xml
```

Has there been a breaking change in the `maven` image I am using for building?

Comment: Create an newline between the `--settings` and the parameter..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With the introduction of `maven 3.9`, there was a BREAKING CHANGE that affects the parsing of the `maven.config` file:
https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.0/release-notes.html#potentially-breaking-core-changes

> Each line in `.mvn/maven.config` is now interpreted as a single argument. That is, if the file contains multiple arguments, these must now be placed on separate lines, see [MNG-7684](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7684).

As pointed out by @khmarbaise in the comments, adding a newline in the `maven.config` works just fine and is even downwards compatible.

```
--settings
./.mvn/local-settings.xml
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** There must not be a whitespace after `--settings`

Comment: The space after the settings was my issue. TY

Answer (score 7):

Also noticed that `-s./.mvn/settings.xml` works too without any space

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34067312)